# Create dictionary values automatically?

Tags: python, dictionary

So i have a list with strings for path of images:

```
["folder1/_D7327", "folder1/_D7527", "folder2/_D7455", "folder3/_D1237"]
```

I want to automatically create a dictionary to store each photo:

```
{"folder1": ["_D7327", "_D7527"], "folder2": ["_D7455"], "folder3": ["_D1237"]}
```

How can I achieve something like this automatically?

Comment: Check out `collections.defaultdict`!

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault`. For example:

```py
lst = ["folder1/_D7327", "folder1/_D7527", "folder2/_D7455", "folder3/_D1237"]

out = {}
for path in lst:
    folder, file = path.split("/")
    out.setdefault(folder, []).append(file)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'folder1': ['_D7327', '_D7527'], 'folder2': ['_D7455'], 'folder3': ['_D1237']}
```